# WebStorm can't recognize "readonly" of Ng2?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webstorm

WebStorm compile error. The following code from ng2:

```
export declare class NgForRow {
    ....
    constructor($implicit: any, index: number, count: number);
    //when remove readonly,it works!
    readonly first: boolean;//has compile error
    readonly last: boolean;//has compile error
    readonly even: boolean;//has compile error
    readonly odd: boolean;//has compile error
}
```

> Error:(7, 14) TS1005: '=' expected.
>
> Error:(7, 19) TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> Error:(8, 14) TS1005: '=' expected.
>
> Error:(8, 18) TS1005: ';' expected.

[image]

Comment: What's your WebStorm version exactly (`Help | About`)?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21317#comment=27-1410316

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript compiler bundled with WebStorm (1.8.10 in most recent version) doesn't have  'readonly' modifier support. You can try using standalone TypeScript compiler instead, by choosing 'custom' compiler version - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/transpiling-typescript-to-javascript.html#d239602e138.

See [WEB-21317](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21317)

Comment: but angular 2 only requires 1.8.10, and in fact the quickstart app only requires "^1.8.10" in the package.json

Comment: you should not even have to compile the libraries... ignore the node_modules directory. dependency injection will already import your type definitions from these modules.

Answer (score 1):

Webstorm doesn't support TypeScript 2.0 yet.

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/readonly.html

## Options

Use some other editor that support TypeScript cutting edge (I am writing [alm.tools](http://alm.tools/) and wrote atom-typescript) or just tolerate the error in the IDE (but keep it green on the console).

Comment: but angular 2 only requires 1.8.10, and in fact the quickstart app only requires "^1.8.10" in the package.json

Comment: What is says and what it does is different I guess. You need typescript nightly

Comment: More https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html#nightly-typescript

Comment: you should not even have to compile the libraries... ignore the node_modules directory. dependency injection will already import your type definitions from these modules.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to not compile the dependencies, you only really need to compile your application. In your `tsconfig.json` file be sure to exclude node_modules:

```
  //tsconfig.json
  {
     "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
       ...
     },
     "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
     ]
  }
```

be sure webstorm is set to use the tsconfig. You may have to restart WS, as I had to do this to get it to actually load the changes. This should bypass and need to upgrade to TS2 until it is production ready.

**What's the trick?**

You might think that ignoring the node_modules directory will not allow TS to load the definitions, but not so. In your Angular2 classes, you explicitly import ng modules:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

Therefore, these modules' definitions will be explicitly loaded as long as your module loader is accurately configured:

```
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```